# Incompatiblity between SATA hard drive and USB dock

Tags: usb, ssd, external-hard-drive, sata

This question resembles [an older one](https://superuser.com/questions/900766/hard-drive-sata-making-trouble-when-connecting-via-usb) but is different, as the older question deals with a software-level incompatiblity problem and mine is a physical, hardware-level incompatiblity problem.

I have a USB dock for external hard disks :

[image]

The info on the bottom of it says "Hard disk cloning device. Output Interface : USB 3.0/2.0 OTB OTC. HDD Compatible: ALL 2.5"OR 3.5"SATA HDD"

I also have two hard disks I pulled from dead MacBooks, a "blue" and a "grey" one (see images below).

[image]

[image]

I have been using the blue one for years in combination with my dock without any problems, but the grey one on the other hand seems physically incompatible with the dock (I tried a dozen times, and failed every time to make the grooves fit into the compartment and hold straight). I find that surprising as the grooves look pretty identical to me :

[image]

Info on the blue hard disk : HITACHI, HDD 5K750-500 HTS547550A9E384, Type TS5SAD500, SATA 700mA DC, 2.5 inch AT 9.5mm.

Info on the gey hard disk : HITACHI, D33373, N13508, HTB-HTSS43232L9SA0 (B) 020-6223-A FLBFS 655 - 1440C xIX9150ZLXSA4Ax

Answer (score 2):

For the record, I answer my own question (although the credit really goes to a now-deleted comment to the OP).
The "grey disk" turned out to be just another blue disk with a detachable half-metallic, half-cardbaord grey cover (note the small screws in the picture : you have to unscrew four of them to detach the cover) :

[image]

Comment: The metal tray should probably return where it came from, otherwise mounting another drive there would be difficult :)